# Moduli functor with no coarse moduli space

Tags: moduli-space

I have the following problem. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the set of isomorphism classes of invertible complex 3$\times$3 matrices. If we have a variety $X$, a family over $X$ is a matrix $A(x)$ with coefficients in $\mathcal{O}(X)$ such that $A(x)$ is invertible for any $x\in X$. This define a moduli problem.

My question is, why the associated moduli functor has no coarse moduli space?

Any idea will be appreciated.

Comment: What are your isomorphisms between matrices? Conjugation?